# Save Database values in textfield on page load in drupal 7.0

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

This query returns a name:

```
$result=db_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE users.uid=:uid",array(':uid'=>$artcheckin))->fetchField();
```

and now I want to save the name retrived in the textfield on form load.

This doesn't work:

```
$form['name']['#default_value'] =$result;
```

What hook for page loading should I use so that values are stored in the textfield from the database at the time of page load?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to tap in to [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). You can use this to print out the form_id on the page and then create a form specific hook as such:

```
function hook_form__form_id_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $result=db_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE users.uid=:uid",array(':uid'=>$artcheckin))->fetchField();
  $form['name']['#default_value'] = $result;
}
```